How do I forward some messages received by my personal number to my Twilio number?
I'm developing a program that needs to read my personal messages. For that, I'm trying to forward messages sent to my number to my Twilio number, as long as they contain a specific word (say, "banana"). Here's a visual representation of the forwarding chain:
MESSAGE CONTAINING "banana" --> MY PERSONAL NUMBER --> MY TWILIO NUMBER
Is there any way to achieve this on Twilio?

Google Voice used to allow SMS forwarding, but they removed it a few years ago unfortunately. According to this article, Google Voice can forward incoming messages to your email, so you might be able to set up something with your email to trigger a call to the Twilio API? It's a really roundabout way, but it could work?
Otherwise, you would need a mobile application with permission to access your incoming text messages, and then that application could forward the text to your Twilio number. Twilio itself does not offer a product that could do what you are looking for.
